# MySql error when trying to combine two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-like, android-room

Hi i am getting the error below when i am tryin to combine two tables, Post and User

> error: extraneous input 'post' expecting {, ';', K_ALTER, K_ANALYZE, >  > K_ATTACH, K_BEGIN, K_COMMIT, K_CREATE, K_DELETE, K_DETACH,
>   K_DROP, K_END, K_EXPLAIN, K_INSERT, K_PRAGMA, K_REINDEX, K_RELEASE,
>   K_REPLACE, K_ROLLBACK, K_SAVEPOINT, K_SELECT, K_UPDATE, K_VACUUM,
>   K_VALUES, K_WITH, UNEXPECTED_CHAR}

I have a table that has a number of posts which consists of a title, body and by which user created that post,

The user table is a list of users details such as there names and addresses.

I am trying to create a resultset that outputs the post details such as the title and body, plus the user's username attached to it(the post table only has a user id reference)

This is my query i tried

```
SELECT post.title AS title, post.body AS body, post.username AS username FROM post, user, WHERE user.id = post.userId
```

My sql skills are a bit rusty but i believe the above use case query can be done?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a table join. I assume when you wrote post.username you mean user.username, since you later say that the post table only has a userId reference.

Something like this might be what you want:

```
SELECT post.title, post.body, user.username
FROM post
INNER JOIN user
ON post.userId=user.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try something like this:

```
SELECT p.title AS title,p.body AS body,p.username AS username 
FROM post p 
JOIN user u ON u.id = p.userId
WHERE u.id = 'to your user id'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Query looks good but remove the comma before where clause:

**from**

```
SELECT post.title AS title, post.body AS body, post.username AS username FROM post, user, WHERE user.id = post.userId
```

**to**

```
SELECT post.title AS title, post.body AS body, post.username AS username FROM post, user WHERE user.id = post.userId
```